# ProxyPass to mean app

Tags: apache, mean-stack

I wrote a mean app.
Till now the node.js server is also serving the angular2 content. I do this by including the following lines in the app.js:

```
app.use(express.static('./client'));
app.use(express.static('./client/src'));
```

The app works fine.
Now I would like to host my app on a server behind apache2:
What I did is adding this line in my VirtualHost configuration:

```
ProxyPass /path http://127.0.0.1:3000
ProxyPassReverse /path http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

When I browse to https://www.myserver.com/path I get:

GET 
https://www.myserver.com/path --> request is OK and returns index.html

But the requests for the css an js files are failing because it is looked for them in the wrong path like:

GET https://www.myserver.com/styles.css --> fails (404 file not found)

It should be

GET https://www.myserver.com/**path**/styles.css

How can I fix this?
It is planned that under different paths (/path1,path2,...) different mean apps are running in the future.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Use relative URLs

Comment: Hi. I read about this before. I think I am using relative urls: Isn't <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> a relative url (it s in my index.html)?

Comment: is it the same if you go to http://www.myserver.com/path/ (with the trailing slash)?

Comment: yes it is the same

Answer (score 0):

I am stupid.
I just had to change the

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href="path">
```

in the index.html of the angular app